# Use just the ServiceStack logging without the entire web service stack

Tags: .net, servicestack, log4net

Is it possible to just use Func and ServiceStack.Logging to use Log4net without using the full ServiceStack web framework?  If so, do I still need an AppHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the logging providers, like most major sub components in ServiceStack are completely independent which sees all logging providers, including [ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net/) only having a dependency on **ServiceStack.Common**, so doesn't require a reference to `ServiceStack.dll`.